# Error on running Office Add In in IE

Tags: office-js

One of the Office Add-ins I am building works fine on Chrome, however on IE I get an error:

`SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function.`

Comment: Could you clarify how you are running it on Chrome? Ordinarily, just pasting the URL of the add-in's web app into a browser will load the page, but your Office JS code will not initialize or work outside the context of a host Office application.

Comment: Hi Rick, I was testing the behavior in Excel online running on Chrome and IE.

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? This error isn't specific enough to isolate what is happening.